# How can I add a prefix to values in yaml?

Tags: yaml

I've tried searching for this and I'm possibly using the wrong terms for what I want, but I can't find anything.

I have a yaml file as follows:

```
a:
  b:
    prefix: vp_

c:
  d:
    some_value: hello
```

What I want is to append the prefix above to "some_value" like this

```
prefix: &vp_
some_value: *{prefix}hello
```

or however the syntax would be. Is this possible? The reason is that I could do this when reading the yaml file, but it's more elegant this way I feel, if possible.
Thanks :)

Comment: This is not possible with pure YAML. You would need to post-process it with a templating system, like ansible does, for example. It depends on which language/YAML processor you use how easy that would be.

Comment: I'm using python so I fixed it on that end. No biggie :p Just thought to ask because it would look prettier that way. Thanks for answering!